# Click event on dynamic element in dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery dialog, that's loading a small form when it opens. There is a button in this form `<input type="submit" class="cancel" value="" />`. When this is clicked, I'd like the jQuery dialog to close.

Here's what I have:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).load("@Url.Action("Create")");
    }
});


$('input.cancel').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    alert("hello");
    //$("#dialog").dialog('close');
});
```

But clicking on my Cancel button, it just reloads the entire page. Even if I change it to an alert, it still just reloads the entire page.

Am I doing something wrong here? I thought `on` would attach to a dynamic element, and `e.preventDefault()` would stop it from submitting the form.

Comment: You need the `$(container).on('event','selector', function() {...})` version of `on()`... maybe `$(document).on('click', 'input.cancel', function() {...});`

Comment: Yeah you seem to be missing your `selector` / `container` combination.

Comment: change the type from `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

Comment: instead of prevent default you can use return false also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the type from `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

```
<input type="button" class="cancel" value="" />
```